# MacBook Air M2 Dual Monitor Setup

Tags: macbook-pro

I am connecting two Samsung 24” monitors (CF24F390 - 1080p) to a new MacBook Air M2.

One monitor is connected through an HDMI to a USBC hub and the second monitor is connected through a Wavlink HDMI to USB adapter then to the USBC hub.

But finding the text is very pixelated. I have played with the Display Settings and all I see is the 1080p, which it's set at.

Wondering if there is a fix

Comment: 1080p on a 24" screen will not be smooth compared to the built-in display, just because of 'physics'. That's going to be a fairly jaggy display in any case. You mean it's unexpected, or worse than reasonably expected?

Answer (score 1):

A 24-inch display with a resolution of 1920 x 1080 pixels has a pixel density of 92 pixels per inch. Each pixel is about 0.28mm!

Your MacBook Air has a display that is 2560 x 1664 pixels in 13.6 inches, giving a density of 224 pixels per inch -- over 2.4x smaller pixels.

macOS is designed to work with high-density displays, using scaled resolutions. Anything below 140 ppi is going to look pixelated, or blurry.

Even a 2K resolution (2560 x 1440) at 24 inches only gives you 123ppi.
A 4K display at 27" inches gives you 163ppi.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot in understanding the issue. Looks like I might need to upgrade the monitors.